# How can I use Sparrow to send iCal e-mail notifications instead of Mail.app?

Tags: ical, sparrow

I am really annoyed how iCal uses Mail.app to try to send e-mail notifications. It always pops up Mail.app and I do not want it to at all. How can I make iCal use Sparrow instead to send e-mail notifications/reminders?

I tried this: http://gidogeek.com/post/6037637963/ical-sparrow

But that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Related but not an exact duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24576/how-do-i-stop-ical-from-launching-mail-app

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but there was not a real solution.

Comment: Are there any other solutions where you do not need to do any coding changes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution to your issue but it requires a little AppleScript jiggery pokery.

Johan Bruning posted [an AppleScript for this on GitHub](https://github.com/JohanB/ical_sparrow/zipball/master). He's included instructions for installing it in the README which is also [visible on the project's GitHub page](https://github.com/JohanB/ical_sparrow).

In his [blog post about the script](http://gidogeek.com/post/6037637963/ical-sparrow) he writes, "I am happy to report it works like a charm and my iCal now finally sends e-mails trough Sparrow."

Comment: That is the same link that I posted, but after installing the script, it still didn't work for some reason. I tried a few tests and it was still popping up Mail.

Comment: I'm the author of the original script, and it all depends on which version of Mac OS you are using. It does not work on 10.8 currently. And I did not intend to work on the script any longer after Sparrow was purchased by Google and support for it was discontinued. I still use Sparrow however and I might end up updating the script.

Answer (score 0):

It is still using Mail.app because the script from github is the original. You need the other one which seems to be missing. Someone will need to contact the author to let him know that it is not showing up.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit? Between "it" and "the other one" and "seems to be" and "which author" are questions that come to mind. If you have a real answer, please elaborate a bit but I don't see how this is a solution to the problem posed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I'm not sure about the specifics of your question/input, but I can confirm that the modified script does not function as the author intended (or confirmed as such). Apple Mail is still used to send notifications of iCal events even though I have completed the script workaround originally mentioned.